# why spring boot always output info level log after change the log level

Tags: java, spring-boot

Today I changed my spring boot application log level from INFO to WARN in application.yaml like this:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    org:
      springframework:
        web: WARN
```

next step I checked the application log level like this and make sure it take effect:

```
> curl http://localhost:11014/actuator/loggers|jq '.'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7751    0  7751    0     0  55468      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 55762
{
  "levels": [
    "OFF",
    "FATAL",
    "ERROR",
    "WARN",
    "INFO",
    "DEBUG",
    "TRACE"
  ],
  "loggers": {
    "ROOT": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.cfg": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.cfg.context": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.cfg.context.DefaultConstraintMapping": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryConfigurationHelper": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.groups": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.groups.ValidationOrderGenerator": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorDescriptor": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorResolver": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.CascadingMetaDataBuilder": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.rule": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.rule.MethodConfigurationRule": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.AnnotationProcessingOptionsImpl": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.ProgrammaticMetaDataProvider": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.raw": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.raw.ConstrainedExecutable": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.properties": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.properties.DefaultGetterPropertySelectionStrategy": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.properties.javabean": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.properties.javabean.JavaBeanExecutable": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.properties.javabean.JavaBeanParameter": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Contracts": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableHelper": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ReflectionHelper": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeVariables": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.GetInstancesFromServiceLoader": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.LoadClass": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.jboss": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.jboss.logging": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.springframework": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    },
    "org.springframework.web": {
      "configuredLevel": "WARN",
      "effectiveLevel": "WARN"
    }
  },
  "groups": {
    "web": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "members": [
        "org.springframework.core.codec",
        "org.springframework.http",
        "org.springframework.web",
        "org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web",
        "org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans"
      ]
    },
    "sql": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "members": [
        "org.springframework.jdbc.core",
        "org.hibernate.SQL",
        "org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

when I restart the application, it still output the info level log like this:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.7)

[main] INFO com.ctrip.framework.foundation.internals.provider.DefaultApplicationProvider - App ID is set to 0010010001 by app.id property from System Property
[main] INFO com.ctrip.framework.foundation.internals.provider.DefaultServerProvider - Loading /opt/settings/server.properties
[main] INFO com.ctrip.framework.foundation.internals.provider.DefaultServerProvider - Environment is set to [DEV] by property 'env' in server.properties.
[main] INFO com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.DefaultMetaServerProvider - Located meta services from apollo.meta configuration: http://localhost:8080!
[main] INFO com.ctrip.framework.apollo.core.MetaDomainConsts - Located meta server address http://localhost:8080 for env DEV from com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.DefaultMetaServerProvider
[main] INFO com.dolphin.soa.post.AppStarter - Starting AppStarter using Java 11.0.14.1 on xiaoqiangs-MBP with PID 30794 (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire/dolphin-post/dolphin-post-service/build/classes/java/main started by xiaoqiangjiang in /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire)
[main] INFO com.dolphin.soa.post.AppStarter - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
[main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope - BeanFactory id=8dd079fe-44e6-3ddc-8f0f-827255756eb4
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'redisConfig' of type [misc.config.redis.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec83d76b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 11014 (http)
[main] INFO org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-11014"]
```

what should I to do change the log level? Am I missing something?